# Does being trivially copyable imply being nothrow copyable?

Tags: c++, c++17

Alternatively, is there an example of a type with a copy constructor that can throw, but is nontheless trivial?
And if not, does that imply that the `is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>` should be true whenever `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` is true?

Note that according to the standard ([latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf) [23.15.4.3]), for a type T to be nothrow copyable, we need the expression `T t(declval<const T&>());` to be a well-formed variable definition that is **known not to throw any exceptions**. This wording seems to be somewhat vauge to me - what does it mean for something to **be known**? Should the `noexcept` specifier be sufficient to establish that knowledge? or maybe the determination is left to the implementation?

---

**Edit:** I realize there's a difference between being trivially copyable, and being trivially copy constructible. My focus is on the latter.

Answer (score 7):

> Does being trivially copyable imply being nothrow copyable?

No. For example:

```
struct X {
    X(X&& ) = default;
    X(X const& ) = delete;
};
```

This type is trivially copyable, but not nothrow copyable... or even copyable at all.

---

However, *given* that a type is copyable<sup>†</sup> *and* trivially copyable, then it must be copyable without throwing (any potential exception would have to come from a non-trivial copy, which can't exist).

<sup>†</sup>Simply defaulting a copy constructor but marking it `noexcept(false)` defines it [as deleted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.default#3), so such a type would not be copyable.

Comment: @user2357112 Right, I made the mistake of equating "nothrow copyable" with "copy can't throw".

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit.

Comment: Since the `noexcept(false) = default` example turns out to be non-copyable, I wonder if there's any way to produce a copyable, trivially copyable type that's still not nothrow copyable.

Comment: Yes, isn't it fantastic that something which is Trivially Copyable is not necessarily copyable?

Comment: Interestingly, according to the standard, even though `X` is trivially copyable, `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<X>` should be false.

Answer (score 3):

On a compiler that implements [DR2171](https://wg21.link/CWG2171):

```
struct X {
    X(X&) = default;
    template<class U> X(U&&){ throw 1; }
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<X>, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<X>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<X>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<X>, "");
```